# Activity trace of rejected edit delayed 90+ minutes, except by deep digging in timeline

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review, suggested-edits, timeline

The following is a link to a rejected pending edit.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16802440

The issue I am raising here is not the specific rejection -- *that kind of question I would put on SO's own meta page* -- but rather I want to discuss a more general issue of an apparently ongoing problem with how SE/SO works.

I say "ongoing" because there are a number of similar meta questions about "*pending edits missing*". Either these vanishing edits are a recurring bug in the software or else there is a human/system communication breakdown in how users are informed of the edit review process and outcomes.

HERE IS WHAT I DID:

On **StackOverflow** I made an edit to a quite correct and officially Accepted answer (I did not alter the answer, just added some information). It was flagged "pending peer review" and I went off to do some other things. I then later returned and the edit had vanished as if I had never made it. There was no "rejected" message in my inbox and there is no trace of the edit or the rejection in any of my activity tabs.

I only found the above link by drilling down through the *timeline* links multiple levels:

- I started with the question link:

[Do 'starts_with' and 'start_with' have the same function in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945669)

- I then *manually* converted this link to show the question timeline:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34945669/timeline

- On that page I found the *timeline* link for the **Answer**:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34945754/timeline

- Which then provided the *suggested edit* link for the **Review**:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16802440

My question then is why was there no notice and no trace of the edit/review/rejection in my Activities tab?

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/4509085/o-m-y?tab=activity

---

CRAP! Okay now that I have typed all this I went back and double-checked all my links before clicking the POST button and it seems that when the User page updated the rejection has **finally** showed up on my Activity tab, albeit more than TWO HOURS after the event. (I had updated that page less than 30 minutes ago so the delay could be as little as about 90 minutes.)

**So my question has *changed* to:**

Why was there such a substantial delay in the Activity showing up on my User page? and Why is there no notification of the rejection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so looking through your access history, you never visited the correct place to find the information. You clicked on the top tabs of your profile to go through a bunch of different irrelevant lists.

You *did* at one point click on the correct "all actions" tab in your profile, but if you had previously clicked on one of the sub-tabs inside there, it would have loaded the incorrect page based on what you accessed last. Under all actions, you need to either select the suggestions filter or the all filter to see your suggestions.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: That's... a perfect free hand double headed arrow. Oh, and guess a perfect answer to such question. :)

Comment: Does the profile page come with a users's manual ? Seems like maybe it needs one if it is that finicky.  :)

Answer (score 3):

> I then later returned and the edit had vanished as if I had never made it

Wrong. It is visible to everyone, including you of course, in your profile page under Activity --> all actions --> suggestions: ([direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4509085/o-m-y?tab=activity&sort=suggestions))

> [image]

Comment: Please read to the end of my question, the message you circled in red showed up somewhere between 90-120 minutes after the rejection. I will edit this questions title to reflect that.

Comment: @O.M.Y. this is most likely caching on your side. The profile page is not live. To see changes, you have to reload it. If you reload and see no changes, something on your side is caching the contents in aggressive way that SE can't control. Believe me, there is no server side cache for this. Once you suggest an edit, it appears there.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you, except I had not been on the profile page for SO for months prior and I had rebuilt my OS about two weeks ago. I only went to the profile page *after* I could not see my edit.

Comment: @O.M.Y. so as the comment on your question suggests, you must have seen a different activity tab, e.g. [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4509085/o-m-y?tab=activity&sort=reviews), which indeed does not contain your suggested edit. Keep in mind that the site "remembers" what tab you last visited, even years after last visiting, so that is the tab you see when going to the activity tab. (sigh, I see you got same response from animuson. :))

Comment: As I just told @animuson above: I walked through **every** activity tab trying to find the suggested edit. It was not there. I am a very methodical person and I spent a number of years in IT as a specialist in documenting and analyzing problems. I have no idea why or how but it was delayed.

Comment: @O.M.Y. well, one thing is for sure, this can't be reproduced anymore, otherwise we would be getting here tons of such bug reports. Worst case, it was some weird temporary glitch in the system, but still... find it hard to believe.

Comment: I agree. Do a quick search on the SO meta and you will find a few folks asking about "missing pending edits" spread out over time. This may indeed be a very sporadic bug, lucky me. :P

Comment: Are you on a distributed server structure? I suppose this could be an odd propagation delay maybe?

Comment: Thanks for trying Shadow Wizard. Appreciate the effort.

Comment: @O.M.Y. "distributed server structure"? Not sure what you mean, anyway I'm the wrong person to ask, not working for SE. :)